# Problems with youtube api & google people api & brand accounts

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I've created a google signin app, which uses the Google People API service. However I also need to access the users youtube channel.

This can present the signing-in user with the option of selecting which channel they want to sign in with. If they sign in with their main account, theres no problems.

However its highly likely they'd have more than one channel (now called a Brand Account). The problem here is that I'll get the correct youtube channel ID, but the user details will be for the brand account, and the email is hard-coded email like : testing-1234@pages.plusgoogle.com

Looking at the brand account management page, it says that sending to that email should get sent on to the main account holder. However this is most definetely not happening.

I've also tried an auto-incremental approach to requesting permissions but that doesnt work either as each users account is directly linked to a youtube channel, and once signed in will just return the default one for that (brand) account.

Im just not sure how Im meant to reliably get a persons (valid) email address and the youtube channel they want to use with our system.

Any pointers much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I know that you can use google sign in to authenticate a login to a youtube channel.  That sign in asks for the email account that is associated with the channel.  I believe  (in the android code I work on at least) I can get to a channels list from there. But a user could pick any email address from the initial login to get  to the youtube account associated with that email address if they have the credentials.

this has a way to execute requests on the api and an update function too.

[Branding channels](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels)

This is a sample that gets a channel list and then uses index 0 for the channelId:

```
 YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(transport, jsonFactory,
                    credential).setApplicationName(getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .build();


            YouTube.Playlists.List playLists;
            PlaylistListResponse playlistListResponse = null;
            List<PlaylistData> PlaylistData = new ArrayList<PlaylistData>();


            try {

                ChannelListResponse clr = youtube.channels().list("contentDetails")
                        .setMine(true).execute();

                playLists = youtube.playlists().list("id,status,snippet");
                playLists.setChannelId(clr.getItems().get(0).getId());
```

Comment: examples would be appreciated

Comment: is this for an app?